# Proving a logarithmic inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms

I'm interested why this is true:

$$ \text{Considering }\forall (x,y,z) \in (1,\infty)  $$

The following holds:

---

> $$\log_xy^z+\log_x{z^y}+log_y{z^x} \geq \frac{3}{2}$$

---

This is taken from a high school textbook of mine. I tried finding a meaningful manipulation by using AM-GM, but that got pretty messy. I'd like to avoid Lagrange multipliers since this is meant to be a pretty basic problem.

Any progress would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not true as written; for example, take $x=1.1$, $y=1.01$, $z=1.001$.  Should $x,y,z$ occur cyclically?

Comment: Didn't notice that. You're probably right, high school textbooks are known to be pretty sloppy.

Answer (score 1):

CW answer to remove it from unanswered queue:

For $(x,y,z)=(1.1, 1.01, 1.001)$, the expression is clearly $\simeq 0.22<\frac{3}{2}$, contradicting the inequality at hand.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Set
$$f(x,y,z)=z\frac{\ln y}{\ln x}+y\frac{\ln z}{\ln x}+x\frac{\ln z}{\ln y} $$

look at the stationary point and conclude.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit. I don't want to use any tools beyond high school level.